# Plotting a vector field from spherical coordinates

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration

I am trying to plot an integral that is in spherical coordinates, but I am a bit lost. I think that my only issue is converting to cartesian, everything I have seen on how to do this has gone a bit over my head. Here is my code (sorry about the formatting):

$$
\vec{E}=\sigma k \int_0^R\int_0^{2\pi}[\frac{(r\sin\theta\cos\phi-r'\cos\phi')\textbf{i} +(r\sin\theta\sin\phi-r'\sin\phi')\textbf{j}+(r\cos\theta)\textbf{k}}{(r^2+r'^2-2rr'\cos\phi\cos\phi'\sin\theta-2rr'\sin\theta\sin\phi\sin\phi')^{3/2}}]r'd\phi'dr'
$$

```
\[ScriptR][ϕ_, r_, θ_, ϕ1_, 
   r1_] := {r*Sin[θ]*Cos[ϕ] - r1*Cos[ϕ1], 
   r*Sin[θ]*Sin[ϕ] - r1*Sin[ϕ1], r*Cos[θ]};

\[ScriptR]Norm[ϕ_, r_, θ_, ϕ1_, r1_] := 
  Sqrt[(r*Sin[θ]*Cos[ϕ] - 
        r1*Cos[ϕ1])^2 + (r*Sin[θ]*Sin[ϕ] - 
        r1*Sin[ϕ1])^2 + (r*Cos[θ])^2] // Simplify;

ele[ϕ_?NumericQ, r_?NumericQ, θ_?NumericQ] := σ*k*
   NIntegrate[(\[ScriptR][ϕ, r, θ, ϕ1, 
        r1]/\[ScriptR]Norm[ϕ, r, θ, ϕ1, r1]^3)*
     r1, {ϕ1, 0, 2*π}, {r1, 0, R}];

VectorPlot3D[
 ele[ϕ, r, θ] /. {σ -> 200, k -> 9*10^9, R -> 0.5, 
   r*Sin[θ]*Cos[ϕ] -> x, r*Sin[θ]*Sin[ϕ] -> y,
    r*Cos[θ] -> z}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}]
```

I am worried part of my issue is in the function that I made, but I am most certain that calling replace all like this is not a viable way to transform coordinates.

Edit: added the integral I am trying to solve. The `\[ScriptR]` is the vector in the numerator, and `\[ScriptR]Norm` is the cube root of the denominator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`VectorPlot3D` expects a function of Cartesian $(x,y,z)$ coordinates, but our functions use spherical coordinates.  The solution is use `CoordinateTransform`.  As an example,

```
CoordinateTransform["Cartesian" -> "Spherical", {x, y, z}]

(*   {Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2], ArcTan[z, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]], ArcTan[x, y]}  *)
```

We recognize this result as $(r,\theta,\phi)$.  To make things as simple as possible,  let's define our functions like this:

```
Clear[ele, f, g]

f[r_, θ_, ϕ_][r1_, ϕ1_] := 
    {r*Sin[θ]*Cos[ϕ] - r1*Cos[ϕ1], 
     r*Sin[θ]*Sin[ϕ] - r1*Sin[ϕ1],
     r*Cos[θ]}

g[r_, θ_, ϕ_][r1_, ϕ1_] := 
    Sqrt[(r*Sin[θ]*Cos[ϕ] - r1*Cos[ϕ1])^2 + 
          (r*Sin[θ]*Sin[ϕ] - r1*Sin[ϕ1])^2 +
          (r*Cos[θ])^2
    ]

ele[r_?NumericQ, θ_?NumericQ, ϕ_?NumericQ][R_?NumericQ] :=
    NIntegrate[(f[r, θ, ϕ][r1, ϕ1]/g[r, θ, ϕ][r1, ϕ1]^3)*r1,
      {ϕ1, 0, 2*π}, {r1, 0, R}, AccuracyGoal -> 8]
```

The reason we use those strange definitions is for compatibility with `CoordinateTransformation`.  Now we can pass $(x,y,z)$ arguments to `CoordinateTransformation`, get back $(r,\theta,\phi)$, pass those to `ele` along with $R$ as a separate argument list and get back a Cartesian vector.  Here is one way to plot the vectors:

```
With[{σ = 200, k = 9*10^9, R = 0.5},
 VectorPlot3D[
  (ele @@ CoordinateTransform["Cartesian" -> "Spherical", {x, y, z}])[R],
  {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}]
 ]
```

[image]

What's going on?  First, the `@@` tells MMA to replace the head of `List[r,θ, ϕ]` with `ele`, so we end up with `ele[r, θ, ϕ]`.  Then we follow that with `[R]` separately, all of which evaluates to our vector.  That's the advantage of those strange definitions -- it lets us use `@@` on the first 3 arguments only.

Also, we did not include $\sigma$ or $k$ in our functions and didn't use them in our `With`.  That's because `VectorPlot3D` will rescale the vectors anyway, so it doesn't make any difference.  So, really, the `With` is not necessary.  It's only providing a value to $R$.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed breakdown of what is happening in the code. Super, super helpful